# shouldn't the django todo list example use a foreign key to self?

Tags: django, django-models

In the django todo list example, [available here](http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html), they create a second table of todolist items so that they can reference it with a foreign key.

Is there some good reason why they don't just use a foreign key to self?

```
class DateTime(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.datetime)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.ForeignKey(DateTime)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I think it should look like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.ForeignKey(self)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That's explained in the tutorial: as they admit, it's a "slightly hack-y solution" (actually I'd say *very*) to enable adding multiple items at once via the inline formsets feature of the admin.

Comment: I know why they do it, and I know what it does. The proposal I put forward seems to me to do the same thing, no? Isn't my way of doing things less 'hack-y'?